# Converting hard integral to lambda function with lambdify

Tags: python, function, sympy, integral, lambdify

I would like to lambdify the function `Integral(t**t,(t,0,x))`. It works, but my new function, which was returned by `lambdify`, doesn't return a number but only `sympy.integrals.integrals.Integral` class. But I don't want that, I want it to return a float number.

Here is my code:

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
f = sp.lambdify(x,sp.integrate(t**t,(t,0,x)))
print(f(2)) #return Integral(t**t, (t, 0, 2))
#but i want 2.83387674524687
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lambdify` doesn't support `scipy.integrate.quad` directly [yet](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4471), but it's not difficult to add the appropiate definition. One simply needs to tell `lambdify` how to print `Integral`:

```
def integral_as_quad(expr, lims):
    var, a, b = lims
    return scipy.integrate.quad(lambdify(var, expr), a, b)

f = lambdify(x, Integral(t**t,(t,0,x)), modules={"Integral": integral_as_quad})
```

The result is

```
In [42]: f(2)
Out[42]: (2.8338767452468625, 2.6601787439517466e-10)
```

What we're doing here is defining a function `integral_as_quad`, which translates a SymPy `Integral` into a `scipy.integrate.quad` call, recursively lambdifying the integrand (if you have more complicated or symbolic integration limits, you'll want to recursively lambdify those as well).

Comment: Maybe create a reimann sum first? f = sp.lambdify(x, sp.Integral(t**t,(t,0,x)).as_sum(n = 100))

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i find next solution for this.
I look around this and find out that return lambda is function.
and when you call it with a number it return object (Integarl).

So i can call evalf() to this object and it will return a number.
Like this:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
x = sp.symbols('x')
f = sp.lambdify(x,sp.integrate(t**t,(t,0,x)))
def return_number(z):
    return f(z).evalf()
return_number(2) #return 2.83387674524687
```

It works.

Comment: `evalf` uses mpmath to compute the integral, which can be more accurate than scipy.integrate.quad, but also slower.

Answer (score 0):

Sympy cannot find a closed-form analytic solution for this integral, hence it returns an un-evaluated sympy integral object. Since it appears you are fine with a numerical solution, you can use the scipy's `quad` function for this purpose

```
import scipy.integrate

def f(x):
    return scipy.integrate.quad(lambda t: t**t, 0,x)[0]

f(2)
```

> 2.83387674525

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for that solution, but i want combine sympy and scipy together. Switching from sympy function to scipy and back.