# Lambdify A Parametric Integral

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have the following issue: I want to `lambdify` a `sympy` expression containing parametric integrals like `Integral(tanh(a*x),(x,0,1))`. I tried to do a manual implementation [like here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37469591/9318372)

What we want is essentially that the integral gets converted to something like:

`lambda theta: quad(lambda x: g(x,theta), a,b)[0]`

where

`g = sp.lambdify((x,param), f, modules='numpy'))`

Consider the following MWE:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integral_as_quad(function, limits):
    x, a, b = limits
    param = function.free_symbols - {x}
    f = sp.lambdify( (x,*param), function, modules='numpy')
    return lambda y: quad(lambda x: f(x,y), a,b)[0]

a, x = sp.symbols('a,x')
I = sp.Integral(sp.tanh(a*x),(x,0,1))
K = integral_as_quad(sp.tanh(a*x),(x,0,1))
L = sp.lambdify(a, I, modules=['numpy', {'Integral':integral_as_quad}] )
```

Then calling for example `K(1)` returns the correct value. However `L(1)` gives

```
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'tanh'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

**NOTE:** Doing it manually is no option, since the expressions I deal with are way more complicated and may contain several different integrals. So I really need to get the lambdify working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think returning a lambda from `integral_as_quad` cannot work, because this lambda will never be called, as the `Integral` object in SymPy is not callable. Instead, the parameter tuple can be passed to `quad` via its `args` argument. Another change I made is in the outer lambdification, replacing

```
modules=['numpy', {'Integral':integral_as_quad}]
```

with

```
modules=[{'Integral': integral_as_quad}, 'sympy']
```

The idea is that  at this stage we don't need NumPy functions yet, we just want to replace the Integral by our callable. The order of `modules` list matters: the dictionary comes first to prevent SymPy from keeping Integral as an Integral.

Now L(1) returns the correct amount.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integral_as_quad(function, limits):
    x, a, b = limits
    param = tuple(function.free_symbols - {x})
    f = sp.lambdify((x, *param), function, modules=['numpy'])
    return quad(f, a, b, args=param)[0]

a, x = sp.symbols('a,x')
I = sp.Integral(sp.tanh(a*x), (x,0,1))
L = sp.lambdify(a, I, modules=[{'Integral': integral_as_quad}, 'sympy'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my saviour! And by adding


`a = sp.lambdify( (), a, 'numpy')`


`b = sp.lambdify( (), b, 'numpy')`


`return quad(f, a(), b(), args=param)[0]`


we can even deal with Integral boundaries that are `oo` or depend on `param`!!!!

Comment: Do you think it is possible to generalize this approach to the case when one wants to lamdify a general expression that may contain any number of nested parametric integrals?

Comment: I don't know. Post a new question about nested integrals with a minimal example that's not covered by what's written here.

Answer (score 0):

So one possible workaround I have found, but I am unhappy with because it is too slow for my application, is the following:

```
def to_lambda(expr, param):
    # Preprocessing
    expr = expr.evalf()
    f = sp.lambdify([param], expr, modules='sympy')
    fun = lambda x: np.array(np.array(f(x).evalf()), dtype='float64')
    return fun
```

So first, `expr` gets cast into a lambda function using `sympy`-functions, e.g. we have

`f = lambda a: Integral(tanh(a*x),(x,0,1))`

and then we use `sympy`'s internal integrator via `evalf()` (slow!).

Also, don't ask me why theres the double `np.array`, if one puts the `dtype='float64'` into the first one, then it returns `TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`