# Lambifying Nested Parametric Integrals

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, lambdify

I have a loss function L(u1,...,un) that takes the form

```
L(u) = Integral( (I**2 + J**2) * h, (t,c,d) ) //h=h(t), I=I(t,u)
```

where

```
I = Integral( f, (x,a,b) )   // f=f(x,t,u)
J = Integral( g, (x,a,b) )   // g=g(x,t,u)
```

I want to numerically minimize `L` with `scipy`, hence I need to `lambdify` the expression.

However at this point in time `lambdify` does not natively support translating integrals. With some tricks one can get it to work with single parametric integrals, see [Lambdify A Parametric Integral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173981). However I don't see how the proposed solution could possibly be extended to this generalised case.

One idea that in principle should work is the following:

Take the computational graph defining `L`. Recursively, starting from the leaves, replace each symbolic operation with the corresponding numerical operation, expressed as a `lambda` function. However this would lead to an immense nesting of lambda function, which I suspect has a very bad influence on performance.

Ideally we would want to arrive at the same result as one would by hand crafting:

```
L = lambda u: quad(lambda t: (quad(lambda x: f,a,b)[0]**2 
                  + quad(lambda x: g,a,b)[0]**2)*h, c, d)[0]
```

**MWE:** (using code from old thread)

```
from sympy import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
def integral_as_quad(function, limits):
    x, a, b = limits
    param = tuple(function.free_symbols - {x})
    f = sp.lambdify((x, *param), function, modules=['numpy'])
    return quad(f, a, b, args=param)[0]

x,a,b,t = sp.symbols('x a b t')
f = (x/t-a)**2
g = (x/t-b)**2
h = exp(-t)
I = Integral( f**2,(x,0,1))
J = Integral( g**2,(x,0,1))
K = Integral( (I**2 + J**2)*h,(t,1,+oo))
F = lambdify( (a,b), K, modules=['sympy',{"Integral": integral_as_quad}])
L = lambda a,b: quad(lambda t: (quad(lambda x: (x/t-a)**2,0,1)[0]**2 
     + quad(lambda x: (x/t-b)**2,0,1)[0]**2)*np.exp(-t), 1, np.inf)[0] 
display(F(1,1))
display(type(F(1,1)))
display(L(1,1))
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `integral_as_quad` would re-lambdify the function at every call. It would probably be better to do this at the printer level (you could subclass the lambdify printer, or submit an upstream patch to SymPy to fix it there).

Comment: Here is the SymPy issue https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4471. It hasn't had any discussion in a while, but I think it should not be hard to fix with the improvements that have happened in lambdify since.